# AngularJS set element fixed position based on another element

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This app takes an image, which is essential a background, or workspace.  I need to add input text fields onto this workspace given specific coordinates (top, left, width, height).  These coordinates would be relative to the image (top/left = 0/0).  How would I position my fields/elements relative to the image?

```
        <img id="background" ng-src="{{page.backgroundImage}}" />
        <input type="text" ng-repeat="field in page.fields" ng-model="field.value" 
               ng-style="{position:'absolute',
                              left:field.left,
                               top:field.top,
                             width:field.width,
                            height:field.height}"/>
```

The code above works great for absolute positioning but it is not relative to the image.

Comment: You can use ng-class to dynamically add/remove classes and there's also ng-style if you want to directly bind to style values

Comment: This works great, I still have the problem of how to set my position relative to the other element though.

Comment: Can't you just wrap both the img and input's list into a div with position relative? Then the absolute position of the inputs would be based upon the div?

Comment: I added the code for the entire page so you can see the context.  Wrapping it in a relative position div isn't doing anything.  The image is in the right place, the input box it showing up outside of the image.

Comment: The image should fill the div, and the inputs would be relative to the div therefore relative to the image. If you're going to solve it just with CSS, I'd suggest working on it with static content (no angular) then plug in the ng-style values from your model. Also an example via fiddle or plnkr would be helpful.

Comment: This actually works fine I forgot the quotes around the position:'relative'.. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <img id="background" ng-src="{{page.backgroundImage}}" class="course-image" />
    <input type="text" ng-repeat="field in page.fields" ng-model="field.value"
           style="position:absolute"
           ng-style="{left:field.left,
                       top:field.top,
                     width:field.width,
                    height:field.height}" />       
</div>
```

Comment: Just a little heads-up: It is better not to include contant values in `ngStyle` directive (e.g. `position: 'absolute'`). This causes an extra evaluation per digest loop (and there are several of those going  on all the time). Since it will always evaluate to the same value, just hard-code it in the `style` attribute.

Comment: Just a point in your answer. The attribute style need to be a common html style like: style="position: absolute"